# Aftermarket Head Unit (HU) on Grand Prix 2008

Tags: pontiac, audio, grand-prix

I just finish installing a China brand Android Aftermarket Double Din. The unit has steering wheel controls built in so no extra adapter is required as long as your vehicle does not have a canbus interface. The HU manual says to connect the SWC wire to the Key 1 on the HU iso cable and also connect the ground wire from the factory harness. I came across this [OEM Harness wiring](http://contentdocs.installernet.com/documents/vehicle/12426.pdf), this shows that Pin 7 is the steering wheel control wire and pin 6 is the power for it which I installed both correctly.  Issue is the HU is not recognizing any buttons I press and I know I got the correct SWC wire as I used a multimeter and I was getting different voltage when I was pressing the buttons. I contacted the seller on ebay I know it’s a long shot but he said the steering wheel must have 2 wires, one for ground and one for the buttons.  Does anybody know where I can find the wiring diagram for the OEM harness so I can see if pin 6 instead of installing it to a 12v it may be installed to a ground.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can gather the 2005 and 2008 wiring are the same, you may want to validate further.

Here is the pinout for the radio connector.

[image]